# Why is Ice Cream Sandwich emulator in WXGA720 refusing to start?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have the latest (and only in fact) version of r14 for android, featuring Ice Cream Sandwich, but it doesn't want to start. All of my other emulators are running correctly, but the ICS one makes the AVD Manager screen flickers but nothing else.

There is no error shown on the console or other information that I could use to fix the problem. Would anyone have some idea what is going on? This is all happening on Windows 7.

*Update*

I have played around some more and I can get an ICS emulator to start in 480x800 resolution (WGA800). What seems to be causing the problem is the WXGA720/800 the resolution that the Galaxy Nexus is sporting

Comment: I think you need to update the ADT plugin as well.. Not sure though.

Comment: I had the same issue but I still managed to run WXGA800 by shrinking RAM from 1024MB to 768MB.

Answer (score 2):

I met same problem due to memory limit. Start emulator with higher memory maybe solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not starting of the emulator can be caused by insufficient RAM.

There are three options to make it work:

**1 Make RAM free**

1. Close heavy programs
2. Try again

**2 Reduce "Device RAM size"**

1. Go to the "Android Virtual Device Manager"
2. Create or edit a Virtual device
3. Reduce the "Device RAM Size"
4. Try Again

**3 Buy more RAM**

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue and the resolution selected was wxga720. Device ram size was 1024, I changed it manually to 1024MB and it started displaying the VM and started booting.